# Are the old posts deleted?

Tags: support, deletion

I am wondering if there is a time upper limit for a post such that after that time it is going to be deleted. I mean is every post last forever? If some posts are long lasting what are their qualification?

Answer (score 4):

See FAQ on deleting on meta.SO: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

In particular, you can read there that:

- A question, that has an upvoted answer or has multiple answers cannot be deleted.
- A question can be only deleted by the poster, a moderator, by several users casting vote to delete or, in some occasion, by the system. (Probably the most frequent kind of questions deleted by SE software is an unanswered question, which has negative score, is deleted after 30 days. Another thing you can see rather often is automatic deletion of migration stubs after 30 days.)

Comment: thanks, that really helped